# VS2015 Ripple emulator doesn't load at all

Tags: android, visual-studio, visual-studio-cordova

The project I am trying to load was originally written in Ionic, and has now been imported as Visual Studio project. I've set the project to Debug > Android > Ripple - Nexus(Galaxy), but when I run it, I just get a page that says "Hello, your application is ready!", but nothing I do gets any response from the page.

I am completely new to app dev, I didn't even write this project, I've just been tasked with importing to VS2015. Have I missed something completely here?

Comment: How did you import the project?  Ripple lands on www/index.html by default.  What you are saying indicates you have the default Visual Studio index.html page in your project.

Comment: So how would I go about rectifying that? Have I written over something I shouldn't have? This was the guide I followed: http://www.spritehand.com/2015/04/using-ionic-with-visual-studio-tools.html

Comment: Since this was written, VS has introduced an "import" feature.  Rather than following these directions, instead start VS, go to File > New > Project From Existing Code... and import the Ionic project as an Apache Cordova project.  If you're starting a new Ionic project and are just getting going you may want to [install and use the Ionic template](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b26474d5-c14d-4d69-bad5-37954538c506) that the Ionic team created instead.

Comment: Thanks Chuck! That worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the article you mention was written, VS has introduced an "import" feature.

Rather than following these directions, instead start VS, go to File > New > Project From Existing Code... and import the Ionic project as an Apache Cordova project.

If you're starting a new Ionic project and are just getting going you may want to install and use the [Ionic template that the Ionic team created](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b26474d5-c14d-4d69-bad5-37954538c506) instead.